# OpenDKIM not signing emails

Tags: linux, centos, postfix-mta, dkim

I am trying to configure OpenDKIM to sign emails sent from our website. I am installing it on a CentOS linux server. I have installed opendkim and created all the configuration filed and key files. I cannot figure out why it isnt signing outgoing emails. I have been checking all the configurations but everything seems ok.

Here are the contents of our configuration files(website name changed to example.com for post):

**opendkim.conf**:

```
AutoRestart             false
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
KeyTable                refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
LogWhy                  Yes
Mode                    sv
Domain                  example.com
Selector                default
PidFile                 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha256
SigningTable            refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
Socket                  inet:8891@127.0.0.1
Syslog                  Yes
SyslogSuccess           Yes
TemporaryDirectory      /var/tmp
UMask                   002
UserID                  opendkim:opendkim
```

**TrustedHosts**:

```
127.0.0.1
localhost
*@example.com
*example.com
example.com
```

**SigningTable**:

```
*@example.com default._domainkey.example.com
```

**KeyTable**:

```
default._domainkey.example.com       example.com:default:/etc/opendkim/keys/example.com/default
```

I have been searching through tutorial after tutorial and trying different things in these configuration files, but so far nothing has worked. If anyone knows what I have done wrong here please let me know, thanks!

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I am using postfix and opendkim. Any idea how to solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey everyone I managed to get the dkim working and I just want to post for anyone having this problem in the future. In the end the problem was not with these configurations, but with opendkim itself bugging on our system. It had been started and when we stopped it, it auto restarted and bugged out.

The configurations I used above are correct and work fine.

Comment: `ExternalIgnoreList` is unneeded, `InternalHosts` is enough.

Comment: I am also having the problem. No I dea how to solve it